# systemd service that needs .ssh/id_dsa password

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, services, systemd

I have a systemctl service that starts a process `smd-loop` in a `screen` session. This process requires acces to remote SSH sources (for syncing purposes) and thus needs to be able to access my `id_dsa` private key.

How can I set up the systemd service so that it will work? The following service starts the process correctly but requires me to attach to the screen session and manually type in the `id_dsa` password.

```
[Unit]
Description=smd loop
After=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
User=%i
Group=users
Type=Forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -S smd-loop-win -md "smd-loop"
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

When I manually start `smd-loop` the `id_dsa` password is not required since I've insalled the `pam_ssh` module which starts an `ssh-agent` that holds the password at login.

Comment: I suppose you mean that it needs to access not your public, but private key. Am I correct?

Comment: ah yes it needs the private key. let me fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the identity files containing not encrypted private key into `~/.ssh` directory of the user the service is running. Also, you need to set the HOME environment variable for it, for example if it is run as root:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env HOME=/root /usr/bin/screen -S smd-loop-win -md "smd-loop"
```

Alternatively, if you have a control on how `smd-loop` invokes `ssh` you may add `-I` option to tell the `ssh` an identity file to use.

In any case the identity file has to be owned by this user and has to be accessible by this user only (`chmod 0400 ~/.ssh/id*`) .

Comment: thanks! to be correct `env` should be `/usr/bin/env` because systemd doesn't know where `env` is. also, the command actually is `smd-loop`, `smd-loop-win` is the name of the created screen instance.

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to have the service working while you're logged in, make it connect to the `ssh-agent` that you start with your session. The easiest way to do this is to use a fixed path for the agent socket. Set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable to something like `/home/romeovs/.ssh/darkstar.agent.socket` both in the systemd job and in your `.profile`. Note that if your distribution starts an `ssh-agent` process for you, you may need to kill it, or to leave it unused and replace it with your own. If the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is present in the environment, `ssh-agent` uses the path it contains for its socket. Then, when you log in, run `ssh-add` on your private key, and the job will be able to use it.

If you need to have the job work all the time, I recommend creating a specific passwordless key for that purpose (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/smd.id_rsa -N ''`), and authorize it only to run a specific command on the server by using a `command=` and `from=` restrictions in the [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) file on the server. The `from=` option means that the key is only valid for login attempts from a specific hosts, and `command=` specifies a command that is executed instead of the command specified by the client.

`ssh-rsa AAAA…== romeovs@darkstar no-agent-forwarding no-port-forwarding no-x11-forwarding from="romeovs@darkstar.example.com" command="somecommand --foo"`

The command is executed by your login shell. If you need to pass parameters to that command, you have two choices:

- The original command attempted by the client is in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable. Beware of quoting issues if you attempt to parse it.
- A few environment variables are passed by the client. The exact set depends on the server configuration (`AcceptEnv` directive in the `sshd_config` file).

Answer (score 2):

I would generate an own ssh-key without passphrase for that service.

On the target system(s) I would then use "command=" in the authorized_keys to restrict usage of that key to a single command.

After that, to trigger the target-command you just have to connect to the server - you have to specify nothing else (not event the command) any more.